# How can show message while processing a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

I writing a html page run from file:// (not use webserver)

I want display a message [Loading.....] in div while Page processing create a data
This is my code demo:
before get data i set:

```
$("#msg").html("Loading.....");
```

and after get data i set:

```
$("#msg").html("Done!");
```

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function search() {
            $("#msg").html("Loading.....");
            getData();         
            $("#msg").html("Done!");
        }
        function getData() {
            var html = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
                html += i + "<br>";
            }
            $("#data").html(html);
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="search(); return false;" />
    <div id="msg">Message</div>
    <div id="data"></div>
</body>
</html >
```

How can show message while processing a javascript function?

i try use ajax:

```
function search() {
            $("#msg").html("Loading.....");                  
            $.ajax({               
                success: function () {
                    getData();  
                    $("#msg").html("Done!");
                }
            });

        }
```

But it occuring error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/dt/Desktop/HTMLPage1.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

Comment: Kind of like the error says, `file://` cannot access `XMLHttpRequest` (or `$.ajax`)

Comment: i finding a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there are two problems with this code.

### 1. Trying to make AJAX request over `file://` protocol

That's where you get the error from. Doing this is incorrect because of security of the users.

Imagine, that you visit a random website on the Internet, and it can see all of your files on **your** computer, without even asking for permission or letting you know what it does. In that case, those who use the Internet could say goodbye to private life!

So, instead:

1. If this file will be on **your server**, and you're just testing, then do it on a `localhost` server.
2. If you want to let the user grant access to one of his/her files, use a filepicker (`<input type="file">`).
3. If you want to access users' files without permission, then... look for alternative solutions (web pages cannot do this).

### 2. Synchronous data processing

Once you've somehow solved to get the files, your example will work. But you'll be unable to update the display during processing. That's why your first example doesn't work.

It will also don't let other rendering, or asynchronous JS code to run. Usually, this isn't a problem, as long as *your code doesn't take long time to execute*.

But if it does, you'll need to let some scheduled code to execute, *during* the processing.

You have 2 options:

1. Use a Web Worker to do heavy synchronous operations without freezing the site

   ```
    //your HTML file
    <script>
    async function search() {
        $("#msg").html("Loading.....");
        await getData();         
        $("#msg").html("Done!");
    }
    function getData() {
        return new Promise((rs,rj) => {
            const worker = new Worker('./worker.js')
            worker.onmessage = rs
            worker.onerror = rj
        })
            .then(data => $("#data").html(data));
    }
    </script>
   ```

   ```
    //worker.js
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
        html += i + "<br>";
    }
    self.postMessage(html)
   ```
2. Put `setTimeout(..., 0)` in your processing code to make it asynchronous and the site usable while processing

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        async function search() {
            $("#msg").html("Loading.....");
            await getData();         
            $("#msg").html("Done!");
        }
        async function getData() {
            var html = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
                html += i + "<br>";
                if(i % 10 === 0)
                    //On every 10th iteration, wait some...
                    await new Promise(rs => setTimeout(rs, 0))
            }
            $("#data").html(html);
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="search(); return false;" />
    <div id="msg">Message</div>
    <div id="data"></div>
</body>
</html >
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question!

AJAX and XMLHTTP requests send messages over **HTTP Protocol**. HTTP is a protocol for sending messages over the internet.  You **must** use a webserver, or at least call to localhost, in order to make a HTTP request from your clientside code.

If you really want to just show a "loading" message, sending your request to localhost will at least allow you to "SEND" your HTTP request. Just know that your request will always fail unless you set up a webserver on localhost to answer it. You could write your "Done!" in an ajax fail function in that case:

```
        $.ajax({               
            success: function () {
                getData();  
                $("#msg").html("This will never show up until you set up a webserver that you called from localhost");
            }            
            fail: function () {
                getData();  
                $("#msg").html("Done! (This is showing because you called from localhost)!");
            }
        });
```